# XCTest linker error for custom cocoa touch framework

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode6, linker-errors, cocoapods, kiwi

I created a custom cocoa touch framework, the custom touch framework uses Kiwi pod and thus uses XCTest.

In my framework target I ensured there are no linker flags for XCTest and I Archived the framework and added that to a new project.

In the new project the app builds and upon launch I get this message.

`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest` referenced from the framework I added.

I am not sure why the library is still linking to XCTest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there were reference to the XCTest framework on my targets. I removed them and I didn't have the issue.